# Neat and tidy way to solve php code?

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

How would i go about the following problem which involves running an update query for every row in the array defined below?  I hope it becomes clear...

```
<?php

//Some code

user = array();

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($auctioncheck)){
$fdt[] = $row['finish_time'];
if ($date_time >= $fdt) {
$user[] = $row['current_bidder'];
    {
    {
```

I then want to update a table which sets the value as "user[]".  What is the neatest way of doing this?  I presume it requires a while loop only i don't know how to do it in this context.  So it would be like...

```
 <?php

//Above while loop and then...


$update = mysql_query("UPDATE homepage SET username = '$user[]'...so on");
```

Basically i want the update to be performed for every user[] in the above array.  I might be able to figure it out if i knew how to determine the number of rows in the the user array.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Cheers.

It looks like the for each will come into play.  Only i am now concerned with the elements of multiple arrays being used in the update.

```
$user = array();
$seller = array();



while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($auctioncheck)){
$fdt[] = $row['finish_time'];
if ($date_time >= $fdt) {
$user[] = $row['current_bidder'];
$seller[] = $row['seller'];
 }
 }

 $update = mysql_query("UPDATE homepage SET username = '$user[]'...WHERE username = '$seller'");
```

Any ides anyone for the multiple elements and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$user = array();`

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?php

//Above while loop and then...

foreach($user as $value){
  $update = mysql_query("UPDATE homepage SET username = '$value'");
}

?>
```

Comment: That may well work i'll give a go.  I've not used this before.  So long as the foreach $user is for each $user[] in the array it should work then... Thanks...

Comment: what happens if i have other arrays of which i want to use as updates.  Say...$update = mysql_query("UPDATE homepage SET username = '$value', image = '$value2'2)...would this be represented by foreach ($user as $value AND $image) or something like that.

Comment: That's exactly what it does. It'll loop through each user in the array. You can read up on [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). As for your second question, it doesn't work that way. I'd have to see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not PHP

```
user = array();
```

You are missing the `$`

Besides

where is

```
 {
 {
```

come into play?

Comment: sorry there should be a $.  the two brackets you point out close the if clause and the while clause.  They work fine.